# How can you monitor activity from an App in Azure?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have built a web application that uses Microsoft Graph to connect to OneDrive to upload files to a user's drive.

The web application is registered in Azure under the App Registrations and is also in the Enterprise Applications, having been granted permissions by an administrator to access OneDrive.

There is a section in the Office365 Admin Console to run searches and raise email alerts, however, the user that appears to be performing the action just comes through as 'app@sharepoint', so we cannot monitor what the actual web application is doing because this is too general.

The question I have is, is there any way to specifically monitor what this app is doing, in terms of uploading files or reading files?  I don't know if there is any way set the user that the Enterprise App runs under, or if there is anything that the application can pass to identify itself?

Answer (score 1):

To view a report on user specific activity details on OneDrive connected to via Graph to an app registered on Azure, use GET /reports/getOneDriveActivityUserDetail(period='{period_value}') or  GET /reports/getOneDriveActivityUserDetail(date={date_value}).
You will however need Reports.Read.All application permission.

Please see the following documentation for a better understanding of the usage of this query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0#code-try-1